# New iCloud email added to iPhone5 without changing Apple ID,in order to automatically copy all iMessages that uses that new iCloud email to said email

Tags: icloud, email, apple-id, iphone

If we create another icloud e-mail can we:

1) Add it to our phone to send and receive emails without affecting the Apple ID being used on the iPhone 5?

2) Use that "New iCloud email" to iMessage with a specific person (i.e. Coworker A will only send us texts with their iPhone using that new iCloud email and we'd only contact them and respond to their texts with that new iCloud email?

3) If, all of the above are possible, then could all your conversations with Coworker A be automatically copied to our email? In other words, we can view the conversation on our iMessage and on our email that we added the new iCloud email to?

If not, how can we have our conversations automatically copied to an email in order for us to that not have to screen shot every Conversation which is quite cumbersome?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you break this up into several questions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it is possible to have several iCloud email account on your single iPhone 5. You cannot have multiple Apple ID's on the same phone, but can have many email accounts.
2. No, you really cannot iMessage from multiple iCloud email accounts. That said, it is technically possible, but would require going into the Settings app every time you wanted to message from a different email account and would prove to be quite cumbersome to setup. Even then, they could easily message your other iCloud accounts that were linked to messages. This could quickly result in your having several message threads from the same recipient - an unfortunate situation.
3. Yes, you could technically set up a rule that would forward emails received from the Coworker to another email. Then you could set up that email to automatically tag or mark emails from that iCloud account as read or whatever was needed. It would not be possible with iMessage.

Honestly, it sounds like coercing iCloud and iMessage into what you need is a little too much for what it was designed for. While it *may* be possible to figure a solution out, it is more likely that you could find a third-party solution that would suit you well. Case in point, Google offers Gmail and Hangouts which would allow for emailing and instant messaging - all for free and with associated apps if desired. There is chat history and emails can be archived forever.

Comment: Thank you for your very insightful and detailed response! :)